# Where should I add what in a Smart template project in STS?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

There are a lot of folders in a Smart Template project in STS. My question is where to add what?
There are 4 folders under SRC
1. Main/java.
2. Main/resources.
3. Test/java.
4. Test/resources.
Should I add my controllers in all the above folders or in a few or or or..?

There is another folder called SRC!
Should I use the 'view' folder for adding all my web pages (say JSP pages)?

Can anyone please elaborate?

Also please let me know if using Dynamic Web Project is a better option than using Spring Template project or vice versa?

Comment: check maven project structure

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This folder structure is the [structure of an maven project](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Java classes for your application should be in `src/main/java` for example `src/main/java/com/example/web` (com.example.web is the package)

The JSPs should be in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsps` (*you can use an other subfolder then `jsps` but it must be below `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`*)

> Also please let me know if using Dynamic Web Project is a better option than using Spring Template project or vice versa?

If you know Maven then the Spring Template is better (in my opinion).

*BTW It is important to have `pom.xml` in the project root.*